# Multi level Expandable List

Tags: android, kotlin, expandablerecyclerview

I wanted to know which approach would be the best in order to implement multi level expandable list. I know about Expandable Listview but it only support upto 2 levels but want something for 4 levels. Will it be best to use recyclerview? Its been so long since tried compose so don't know much about it, if there is a better way of doing it in compose kindly let me know. Thank you.

I am thinking about trying recyclerview but haven't tried anything yet